# Heroku deployment error crashing app

Tags: angularjs, node.js, debugging, heroku

I am trying to deploy an angular app with node.js in the back to heroku and I keep getting these errors. I checked heroku logs and this error was returned.

```
$ heroku logs

2017-03-28T19:39:19.558737+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
2017-03-28T19:39:19.558740+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
2017-03-28T19:39:19.558738+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
2017-03-28T19:39:19.558740+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
2017-03-28T19:39:19.558741+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
2017-03-28T19:39:19.558741+00:00 app[web.1]:     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
2017-03-28T19:39:19.558742+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
2017-03-28T19:39:19.558744+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
2017-03-28T19:39:19.558743+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
2017-03-28T19:39:19.558745+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
2017-03-28T19:39:19.558743+00:00 app[web.1]:     at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
2017-03-28T19:39:19.568956+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-03-28T19:39:19.558744+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/bin/www:7:11)
2017-03-28T19:39:19.558746+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
2017-03-28T19:39:19.576891+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-112-generic
2017-03-28T19:39:19.577955+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2017-03-28T19:39:19.578118+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! 
2017-03-28T19:39:19.577095+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! argv "/app/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/app/.heroku/node/bin/npm" "start"
2017-03-28T19:39:19.578397+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
2017-03-28T19:39:19.577245+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! node v6.10.1
2017-03-28T19:39:19.577457+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
2017-03-28T19:39:19.577660+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2017-03-28T19:39:19.577817+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! swiping@0.0.0 start: `node bin/www`
2017-03-28T19:39:19.578260+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the swiping@0.0.0 start script 'node bin/www'.
2017-03-28T19:39:19.580186+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
2017-03-28T19:39:19.578536+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the swiping package,
2017-03-28T19:39:19.578674+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! not with npm itself.
2017-03-28T19:39:19.579513+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
2017-03-28T19:39:19.579652+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     node bin/www
2017-03-28T19:39:19.580319+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm owner ls swiping
2017-03-28T19:39:19.579787+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
2017-03-28T19:39:19.580044+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm bugs swiping
2017-03-28T19:39:19.584013+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-03-28T19:39:19.580460+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
2017-03-28T19:39:19.584213+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
2017-03-28T19:39:19.584307+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/npm-debug.log
2017-03-28T19:39:19.665671+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2017-03-28T19:39:19.683203+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2017-03-28T19:50:32.379502+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2017-03-28T19:50:36.835295+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2017-03-28T19:50:40.588438+00:00 app[web.1]: > swiping@0.0.0 start /app
2017-03-28T19:50:40.588424+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-03-28T19:50:40.588439+00:00 app[web.1]: > node bin/www
2017-03-28T19:50:40.588439+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-03-28T19:50:40.884038+00:00 app[web.1]: { Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '.env'
2017-03-28T19:50:40.884053+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Error (native)
2017-03-28T19:50:40.884054+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:641:18)
2017-03-28T19:50:40.884055+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:509:33)
2017-03-28T19:50:40.884056+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.config (/app/node_modules/dotenv/lib/main.js:30:37)
2017-03-28T19:50:40.884056+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/server.js:7:19)
2017-03-28T19:50:40.884057+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
2017-03-28T19:50:40.884057+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
2017-03-28T19:50:40.884058+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
2017-03-28T19:50:40.884058+00:00 app[web.1]:     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
2017-03-28T19:50:40.884060+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3) errno: -2, code: 'ENOENT', syscall: 'open', path: '.env' }
2017-03-28T19:50:41.499429+00:00 app[web.1]: module.js:471
2017-03-28T19:50:41.499443+00:00 app[web.1]:     throw err;
2017-03-28T19:50:41.499444+00:00 app[web.1]:     ^
2017-03-28T19:50:41.499445+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-03-28T19:50:41.499446+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module 'stripe'
2017-03-28T19:50:41.499447+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
2017-03-28T19:50:41.499448+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
2017-03-28T19:50:41.499450+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
2017-03-28T19:50:41.499450+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/server.js:23:31)
2017-03-28T19:50:41.499452+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
2017-03-28T19:50:41.499449+00:00 app[web.1]:     at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
2017-03-28T19:50:41.499448+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
2017-03-28T19:50:41.499451+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
2017-03-28T19:50:41.499453+00:00 app[web.1]:     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
2017-03-28T19:50:41.499453+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
2017-03-28T19:50:41.499454+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
2017-03-28T19:50:41.499454+00:00 app[web.1]:     at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
2017-03-28T19:50:41.499455+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/bin/www:7:11)
2017-03-28T19:50:41.499456+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
2017-03-28T19:50:41.499456+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
2017-03-28T19:50:41.499457+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
2017-03-28T19:50:41.518990+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-03-28T19:50:41.533527+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-112-generic
2017-03-28T19:50:41.533975+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! argv "/app/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/app/.heroku/node/bin/npm" "start"
2017-03-28T19:50:41.534366+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! node v6.10.1
2017-03-28T19:50:41.534659+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
2017-03-28T19:50:41.534971+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2017-03-28T19:50:41.535416+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2017-03-28T19:50:41.535202+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! swiping@0.0.0 start: `node bin/www`
2017-03-28T19:50:41.536538+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! 
2017-03-28T19:50:41.536786+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the swiping@0.0.0 start script 'node bin/www'.
2017-03-28T19:50:41.537264+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the swiping package,
2017-03-28T19:50:41.537011+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
2017-03-28T19:50:41.538192+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
2017-03-28T19:50:41.537489+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! not with npm itself.
2017-03-28T19:50:41.538418+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     node bin/www
2017-03-28T19:50:41.538660+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
2017-03-28T19:50:41.538885+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm bugs swiping
2017-03-28T19:50:41.539142+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
2017-03-28T19:50:41.539657+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm owner ls swiping
2017-03-28T19:50:41.539883+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
2017-03-28T19:50:41.545636+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-03-28T19:50:41.545943+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
2017-03-28T19:50:41.546128+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/npm-debug.log
2017-03-28T19:50:41.644752+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2017-03-28T19:50:41.660900+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

Any suggestions, I adjusted the package.json to start on node bin/www because that is how I start the app on my local host. There also seems to be a problem with the .env file being seen. And please ignore the errors related to stripe, thank you

Comment: I would recommend removing your .env file from git and not deploying it to Heroku.

Comment: ok I'll try that now, thanks

Comment: You might want to post your package.json since there seems to be multiple issues here.

Comment: I removed the .env file and I am receiving the same errors. Error H10

Comment: How can you say "Please ignore the errors related to Stripe". Some code is expecting to be able to load a module called Stripe and it cannot find it causing the above errors.

Comment: I removed the stripe code right after I posted the question, so its no longer in  the code, thats why I said ignore it

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're missing a Node module by the name of `stripe`. If you've included it in your `devDependencies`, Heroku does not install those. You'll have to move it to the `dependencies` property for it to be properly utilized in your app. You should also remove the `.env` file from your GitHub repo, as toddg describes in his answer.

Comment: But that's what's causing it not to launch. Your `.env` file (or lack of) will not cause the app to not launch (mine does that too); the Node module is what's stopping it from deploying.

Comment: No stripe is removed, I removed it right after I posted the question

Answer (score 0):

Remove your .env from your git repo.

**Create a .gitignore file**

From the command line: `touch .gitignore`

open the file you just created (either use vi or your favorite text editor) and add the following line:

`.env`

Since `.env` is already tracked you'll need to remove it from being tracked:

`git rm --cached .env`

Then commit and redeploy to Heroku

Comment: I do not have a .env file on my git repo

Comment: You need to post your package.json in order for us to help you. There are many issues going on here.

Comment: I fixed the error, the app is now hosted, but does anyone here know why the login feature doesn't work on mobile, I am using Jason Web Tokens to authenticate, do web tokens behave differently on a mobile browser?

Answer (score 0):

Solved problem. Remove all localhost used package.json change the directory to your own app.js or your root js file name. Give ng build. Upload to herokuapp.